# Проблема с отображением картинки в WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

После попытки загрузки картинки в WebView выходит ошибка 
`E/libEGL: validate_display99 error 3008` `(EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)`
И на месте где должна быть картинка белый квадрат. 
Можно ли ее как то решить на высоких версиях Android?

Comment: Слишком мало информации, что бы дать Вам сколько-нибудь полезный совет. Что за картинка, где находится, как попадает в `WebView`? И что значит _на высоких версиях Android_ - на низких работает что ли? Тогда на каких?

Comment: Картинку  использовал во многих расширениях, не помогло, в интернете нашел информацию только про то, что на низких версиях андроид работало.                     В webView попадает по нажатию на listview точнее на фрагмент  в нем

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать другую WebView
https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView